# Drupal timezone information

Tags: php, drupal, timezone

In my drupal installation I can get the offset from UTC in seconds to the timezone I specified in the admin panel using

```
variable_get('date_default_timezone', 0)
```

However, now that we have daylight-saving-time, the time I get is always off by one hour. Is there a way to retrieve the actual timezone string from Drupal, as "Europe/Berlin" for example?

The reason is, that I have to use this with Zend Framework's Zend_Date, but Drupal does not set the PHP default timezone, as

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

gives me System/Localtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

date_default_timezone is only set, when custom user timezones are disabled in the admin panel! Make sure that you check off that option.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `date_default_timezone` should always be *right*.

For example, in France, it should be 3600 in winter (UTC+1), and 7200 in summer (UTC+2).

The thing is the value it contains will not change by magic : there is a `cron` hook called [`date_timezone_cron`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/date_timezone_cron/6) that must be run in order to change that when it's required *(quoting)* :

> Update the site timezone offset when
>   cron runs. 
> This is to make sure
>   that modules that rely on the timezone
>   offset have current information to
>   process.

After that, if you need the name of the current timezone -- the one selected in the admin section -- there is probably another row in the `variable` tables for that.

You could find it with an SQL such as :

```
select *
from variable
where name like '%timezone%';
```

It will most likely return several rows ; but one of them should be the obvious choice.

Judging from the source code of [`date_timezone.module`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--date--date_timezone--date_timezone.module/6/source), I would bet on a variable called `date_default_timezone_name`.